# how to scrape columns In R Programming from Website.?

Tags: r, web-scraping, css-selectors, dplyr, rvest

Can Anyone suggest how can we read Avg Price And Value column in R from the given website.
I am not able to understand what is happening,with the same code i am able to read all the columns except these 2 columns.

The Code I am Using is :

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
url="http://relationalstocks.com/showinsiders.php?date=2017-09-15&buysell=buysell"
url_html<-read_html(url)
SharesTraded_html=html_nodes(url_html,'td:nth-child(6)')
SharesTraded=html_text(SharesTraded_html)
SharesTraded=as.numeric(gsub(",",'',SharesTraded))
AvgPriceDollars_html=html_node(url_html,'td:nth-child(7)')
AvgPriceDollars=html_text(AvgPriceDollars_html)
AvgPriceDollars
```

http://relationalstocks.com/showinsiders.php?date=2017-09-15&buysell=buysell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to do that is to use `html_table` :

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
url <- read_html("http://relationalstocks.com/showinsiders.php?date=2017-09-15&buysell=buysell")
tb <- url %>% 
  html_node("#insidertab") %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
  as.data.frame()

str(tb)
'data.frame':   253 obs. of  9 variables:
  $ Reported.Time: chr  "2017-09-15 21:00:47" "2017-09-15 20:11:26" "2017-09-15 20:11:26" "2017-09-15 20:10:27" ...
$ Tran.        : chr  "2017-09-12  Purchase" "2017-09-13  Sale" "2017-09-14  Sale" "2017-09-15  Sale" ...
$ Company      : chr  "Double Eagle Acquisition Corp." "PHIBRO ANIMAL HEALTH CORP" "PHIBRO ANIMAL HEALTH CORP" "Guidewire Software, Inc." ...
$ Ticker       : chr  "EAGL" "PAHC" "PAHC" "GWRE" ...
$ Insider      : chr  "SAGANSKY JEFFREYChief Executive Officer, Director, 10% owner" "Johnson Richard GChief Financial Officer" "Johnson Richard GChief Financial Officer" "Roza ScottChief Business Officer" ...
$ Shares.Traded: chr  "30,000" "15,900" "39,629" "782" ...
$ Avg.Price    : chr  "$10.05" "$36.46" "$36.23" "$78.20" ...
$ Value        : chr  "$301,500" "$579,714" "$1,435,758" "$61,152" ...
$ Filing       : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```